# Android app that supports Hindi

Tags: java, android, textview

```
   public class ICLLocalization extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.main);
          TextView tv1=new TextView(this);
          tv1.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/mangal.ttf"));
          tv1.setText("इस अंग्रेज़ी हिन्दी अंग्रेज़ी शब्दकोश में आप आसानी से हिन्दी और अंग्रेज़ी शब्दों के अर्थ ढूंढ    सकते हैं। नवम्बर ");
          tv1.setTextSize(20);
          layout.addView(tv1);
         }
   }
```

The Errors are as follows

1. Main cannot be resolved or is not a field.
2. The method addView(TextView) is undefined for the type R.layout.

Comment: you should have your text in the values/string.xml file

Comment: @meh That's good practice, but not necessary

Comment: @DavidCaunt with some languages gibberish can be displayed

Comment: I don't think the Hindi is the problem here. He doesn't have "layout" declared anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Put string to values/string.xml

To ad text view put a wrapper (forexample LinearLayout) to your layout (main.xml)

then find it in onCreate

```
LinearLayout ln = (LinearLayout)findById(R.id.linearlayout_name);
TextView tv1=new TextView(this);
tv1.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/mangal.ttf"));
tv1.setText(R.string.text);
tv1.setTextSize(20);
ln.addView(tv1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this,

`<string name="app_info">इस अंग्रेज़ी हिन्दी अंग्रेज़ी शब्दकोश में आप आसानी से हिन्दी और अंग्रेज़ी शब्दों के अर्थ ढूंढ    सकते हैं। नवम्बर </string>`

to your **res/values/string.xml** file.

In your program, replace this line,

```
tv1.setText("इस अंग्रेज़ी हिन्दी अंग्रेज़ी शब्दकोश में आप आसानी से हिन्दी और अंग्रेज़ी शब्दों के अर्थ ढूंढ    सकते हैं। नवम्बर ");
```

with

tv1.setText(R.string.app_info);

Hope this will work.